# tailwind CSS color setting do not change in react app

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

I'm using React.

I added a lime background to the button when hovering but the effect doesn't show.

My TypeScript:

**button.ts**

```
  <button
    className={`text-lg font-medium focus:outline-none text-black py-4  transition-colors ${
      canClick
        ? "bg-lime-600 hover:bg-lime-700 outline-dashed"
        : "bg-gray-300 pointer-events-none "
    }`}
  >
    {loading ? "Loading..." : actionText}
  </button>
```

It's tailwind.css file

**tailwind.css**

```
@import "base";
@import "components";
@import "utilities";

.input {
   @apply focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500 p-3 border-2  text-lg border-gray-200 transition-colors;
}
```

My JS config file:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors : {
      orange : colors.orange,
      lime : colors.lime,
      sky : colors.sky
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

It works when I use *blue* instead of *lime*. How can I make it work with lime?

Comment: Have you attempted to run `npm run-script dev` again?

Comment: i did `npm run tailwindcss:build`. it's build taildwindCSS

Comment: Do you see the classes in the final css build file?

Comment: @Konrad Actually i found that problem `"tailwind:build": "npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -i src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/styles.css"`. but `styles.css` file is not created.
and happend this error 

**"`focus:border-gray-500` class does not exist, but `focus:border-lime-500` does. If you're sure that `focus:border-gray-500` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree."**

Comment: can you tell me a hint ? 
it's happend in `tailwind.css` 
i don't know what to do..